# Sort struct that contains pointer to the next

Tags: c++, algorithm, pointers

so I have something like:

```
struct Something
{
    int number;
    Something* next;
};
```

And I want to sort them, by the number, though I don't want to change the number, but I want to change the pointer to the next.

How would I do that?

I know the end and the beginning of the "list", (FIFO order)

Comment: do your homework yourself! hint: swap the objects by changing both the pointer `next` and the pointer pointing to the object.

Comment: "struct that contains pointer to the next" is called a linked list.

Answer (score 1):

Use MergeSort for linked lists: first traverse the list with two running pointers, one of them advancing twice slower. When you reach the end of the list, the slow pointer points to the middle. Split the list and sort the halves recursively, then Merge.

Answer (score 0):

There are various sorting algorithms (http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/), and by far, I would use the random|selection one for this example. It will look something like:

```
void Something::SortAscending() {
   Something* current = next;
   Something* smallest = next;
   while( current ) {
      if( current->number < smallest->number ) {
         smallest = current;
      }
      current = current->next;
   }
   if( smallest != next )
      smallest->next = next;
   next = smallest;
   next->SortAscending();
}
```

Note, however, that if you're given the head of the list, you may not change it with the type of function I provided above.

Comment: Not all these algorithms can be adapted to linked lists, and straight selection is not efficient.

Answer (score -2):

Sort -> for each element of sorted array update next pointer